# Не работает admob

Tags: android, admob

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="a1517ea52e9db6a"
ads:adSize="BANNER"

ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

Рекламка тупо не показывается. LogKitten молчит.

p.s. А вот подарок от эклипса (жалоба на ads:*):

```
Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основная ошибка, которая у меня была с **Admob** - то, что не влезал баннер в отведенное место и реклама не показывалась.

Советую попробовать задать ширину как **match_parent**

**UPDATE**

Возможно проблема в том, что xml парсер не понимает префикс **ads**. Для этого надо расширить область видимости. [вот здесь есть пример кода](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6291041/1233682)

Comment: Не помогло

Comment: обновил свой ответ

Comment: С префиксом помогло